# Using Zabbix to monitor the proxy server itself?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, zabbix

Forgive me, this is less "how to" and more "what's the correct *terminology*?"

We have set up a proxy server that uses socks using when communicating with the outside world and an Apache http proxy for inbound traffic. We'd like to use Zabbix to monitor this specific arrangement (or for those searching for similar queries, we'd like to conduct monitoring of a proxy server).

When I Google for documentation, the vast majority of it seems to involve using a proxy server to facilitate Zabbix monitoring of otherwise unreachable resources. Similarly, "reverse proxy" is not fruitful.

How does one search for documentation on monitoring proxies themselves?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to monitor.

- you could monitor that Apache is up or that it or other processes listen on expected ports - these are natively supported by the [Zabbix agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent)
- you could use [web scenarios](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/web_monitoring) to monitor some webpage using a proxy
- you could use [external checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external) or [userparameters](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/userparameters) to execute scripts that would use `curl` or other tools to determine the health of your proxy

Comment: Just to keep folks in the loop, we're experimenting with the user parameters and external checks Richlv recommended before falling back on the Agent. I'll post an update when we decide.